# Web vs. периферия

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, webbrowser, железо

Дано: Web сервер и клиентское устройство. На клиентском устройстве имеются порты (COM, USB и тп.) через которые устройство получает данные от периферии (датчики, сенсоры и пр. оборудование) На устройстве доступен браузер, любые плагины к нему и, в принципе, возможно установить любое доп. п.о.  Клиентских устройств много. Их кол-во заранее не известно.

Вопрос: С помощью каких технологий возможно реализовать первичную обработку и отображение данных с периферийных устройств в браузере на клиентской машине. Ну и передачу данных на сервер ?
Дополнение: Есть ли что-то подходящее в .Net?

В качестве примера: Есть, скажем, датчики температуры, давления и влажности. Подключены к ПК по USB, COM и Ethernet. Я на данном пк открываю в браузере некоторую страницу на моём сервере и хочу чтобы на сервере по данным с датчиков был рассчитан, скажем, прогноз погоды на ближайший час или данные просто были занесены в БД для дальнейшей обработки и, при этом, не хочу ручками забивать показания датчиков в форму для отправки на сервер.

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос вам подойдут любые технологии, которые могут работать с БД и COM портами

Comment: to JK_Action: Хорошо. Я выбираю Borland С++. Он может и с COM и с БД. Расскажите как используя данную технологию реализовать поведение описанное в качестве примера в моём вопросе.

Comment: Плугин к браузеру составленный на Borland C++ с одной стороны подключается к COM|USB, с другой предоставляет API для javascript. Javascript, с одной стороны, пользуясь этим API, запрашивает данные у плугина, с другой, используя AJAX или более современные способы, передаёт эти данные на Web-сервер. Для IE даже плугина не понадобится. Там javascript всегда умел к ActiveX подключаться, если не ошибаюсь. Тогда надо ActiveX сделать

Comment: to banme: Если я выбираю связку IE+ActiveX то единственное, о чём нужно беспокоится владельцу устройства желающему использовать мои сервисы это наличие драйверов для устройств с которых иначе информацию не получить? т.е. подключиться с com или обратится к драйверу я смогу из ActiveX компонента при условии что пользователь разрешит его (ActiveX) запуск?  Или же возможна ситуация когда запуск ActiveX разрешён пользователем но сам компонент запускается "в песочнице" и всё что он может - использовать вычислительные мощности локальной машины, без доступа к переферии, драйверам и файловой системе?

Comment: Я не очень понял, где находится веб сервер на устройстве или где-то на другом пк? Можете ли вы писать по для устройств-сборщиков данных? Что подразумевается под фразой на устройстве доступен браузер? Вы можете использовать устройство как ПК? Или Вы можете подключиться к устройству через http? Конкретизируйте, что за устройство, какая платформа?

Comment: Сервер "где-то". Доступен только по сети. Общение с сервером только по http. П.О. для устройств писать могу, но нужно учитывать что это разные платформы и п.о. периодически обновляется/изменяется. т.е. нужно как-то разруливать вопросы поддержания актуальной версии п.о. на устройствах. Т.е. если и писать п.о. для устройств, то только что-то совсем уж базовое, предоставляющее инструменты для обмена данными с переферией. Под фразой "на устройстве доступен браузер" подразумевается возможность гарантированного запуска полноценных версий большинства из современных общедоступных браузеров.

Comment: Да, я могу использовать устройство как ПК. Строго говоря большая часть из них это ПК под управлением OC Windows XP или 7. Но могут быть и наладонники с Win CE и ПК с *nix и т.п. Теоретически к устройству можно подключиться по http. Если поднять на устройстве соответствующий сервер. Но зачем? По поводу конкретных устройств я уже частью пояснил выше. Они могут быть разные. Единственное, что в них общего: Есть браузер. Возможно установить своё п.о.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно разрабатывать кроссплатформенное ПО для ваших устройств. Технологий тьма что-то конкретное советовать сложно, нужно знать требования по архитектуре и производительности. (С++ Qt/Poco, Python, NodeJS..., если win можно и .net ) Софт этот будет вести сбор данных и передавать на удаленный сервер(HTTP-REST или Websocket). Браузер я вобще не понял зачем тут. На вашем удаленном сервере необходимо организовать бекенд для веб-сервера который будет вести пост обработку. Тут что-то советовать по технологиям, тоже сложно. Не понятно под какой ос сервер и какие требования по произоводительности.

Comment: Браузер тут при том, что логику обработки данных хочется вынести на сервер. А получать результат клиент будет в браузере. А вот теперь интересный момент со сбором: Я своей софтиной собрал и отправил данные на сервер. А потом юзер данного устройства открыл браузер, зашёл на определённую страницу и ожидает там увидеть результаты обработки данных пришедших с его устройства. Вопрос, как мой сервер при http запросе из браузера на клиентском устройстве будет понимать какие данные этому устройству отображать?

Comment: Ещё по поводу софта для клиентских устройств. Его кол-во, размеры, многообразие необходимо сократить до минимума. В идеале вообще отказаться от написания своего п.о. которое устанавливается на клиентскую машину. Именно это основная цель моего вопроса. В идеале хочется найти вариант при котором для клиентских устройств устанавливаемое п.о. не пишется вовсе потому, что его установка/настройка и обновление в моём случае это адовый гемор и источник нескончаемых проблем. (в н.в. используется написанное п.о. которое занимается и сбором, и анализом, и отображением данных на устройстве.